# Customizing TTLauncherView buttons sizes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I'm trying to change the default size of the TTLauncherViewButton items in TTLauncherView, however, i can't seem to find the either the variable or the source code responsible for the size of the buttons in TTLauncherView.

Anyone has suggestions? I'm trying to have bigger buttons in the iPad version.

The only thing resembled sizes i found in the default style sheet:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (TTStyle*)launcherButtonImage:(UIControlState)state {
  TTStyle* style =
    [TTBoxStyle styleWithMargin:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-7, 0, 11, 0) next:
    [TTShapeStyle styleWithShape:[TTRoundedRectangleShape shapeWithRadius:8] next:
    [TTImageStyle styleWithImageURL:nil defaultImage:nil contentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter
                  size:CGSizeZero next:nil]]];

  if (state == UIControlStateHighlighted || state == UIControlStateSelected) {
      [style addStyle:
        [TTBlendStyle styleWithBlend:kCGBlendModeSourceAtop next:
        [TTSolidFillStyle styleWithColor:RGBACOLOR(0,0,0,0.5) next:nil]]];
  }

  return style;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i m not sure about this , but found a alternative - it supports both iphone / ipad

Try this ,

https://github.com/rigoneri/myLauncher

provides same features of TTLauncherView.

Comment: thanks, looks interesting, but i'll be sticking with three20's launcher for now